# From a given row, how to select the previous 'n' rows in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a dummy variable like so:

```
df <- data.frame(year = seq(1990, 1997, 1),
                 x = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))

year  x
1990  1
1991  0
1992  0
1993  0
1994  1
1995  1
1996  0
1997  0
```

I want to create a dummy `y` equalling `1` if the value of `x` in any of the three previous years is non-zero. The expected result:

```
year  x   y
1990  1  NA
1991  0  NA
1992  0   1
1993  0   0
1994  1   1
1995  1   1
1996  0   1
1997  0   1
```

How do I do this? A `dplyr` solution is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know for sure you want 3 values, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(y = sign((x > 0) + (lag(x) > 0) + (lag(x, 2) > 0)))
#>   year x  y
#> 1 1990 1 NA
#> 2 1991 0 NA
#> 3 1992 0  1
#> 4 1993 0  0
#> 5 1994 1  1
#> 6 1995 1  1
#> 7 1996 0  1
#> 8 1997 0  1
```

But a more general solution if you want to choose `n` would be:

```r
n <- 3

df %>% mutate(y = sign(purrr::reduce(seq(n) - 1, ~ .x + (lag(x, .y)))))
#>   year x  y
#> 1 1990 1 NA
#> 2 1991 0 NA
#> 3 1992 0  1
#> 4 1993 0  0
#> 5 1994 1  1
#> 6 1995 1  1
#> 7 1996 0  1
#> 8 1997 0  1
```

Comment: Your soution with n doesn't seem to work, I get a copy of the `x` column. Any ideas?

Comment: @CloftX hmm, works exactly as shown with `n = 3` If I run my code in a fresh session with `library(dplyr)` then input the above, it gave me this exact output. The output is as expected with different values of `n` too. Have you tried this in a fresh session?

Comment: I will try in a new session, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `zoo`s `rollapply`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(y = rollapply(x, width = 3, \(x) any(x > 0), align = "right", fill = NA)*1)
```

or in more concise many thanks to @G. Grothendieck:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% mutate(y = + rollapplyr(x > 0, 3, any, fill = NA) )
```

```
 year x  y
1 1990 1 NA
2 1991 0 NA
3 1992 0  1
4 1993 0  0
5 1994 1  1
6 1995 1  1
7 1996 0  1
8 1997 0  1
```

Comment: This can be written compactly as `df %>% mutate(y = + rollapplyr(x > 0, 3, any, fill = NA) )`

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned dplyr is preferred (Allan Cameron's solution is a perfect `dplyr` approach), but for posterity and those who may not use `dplyr`, a base R solution could be to use `vapply`:

```
n <- 3
rws <- seq_len(nrow(df))[-(1:(n-1))]

df[rws, "y"] <- vapply(rws, \(x) +(sum(df$x[(x - 2):x]) > 0), 1)

#   year x  y
# 1 1990 1 NA
# 2 1991 0 NA
# 3 1992 0  1
# 4 1993 0  0
# 5 1994 1  1
# 6 1995 1  1
# 7 1996 0  1
# 8 1997 0  1
```